# pyenv modifies my prompt for versions with words but not the purely numbered ones

Tags: python, bash, pyenv

The following lines were added to my .bashrc :

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

The following lines in the terminal illustrates the problem:

```
cardamom@neptune ~ $ mkdir testDirectory
cardamom@neptune ~ $ cd testDirectory
cardamom@neptune ~/testDirectory $ pyenv versions
* system (set by /home/felix/.pyenv/version)
  3.4.3
  3.5.0
  project1
  miniconda2-latest
  miniconda3-latest
  miniconda3-latest/envs/project1
cardamom@neptune ~/testDirectory $ pyenv local miniconda3-latest
(miniconda3-latest) cardamom@neptune ~/testDirectory $ pyenv local miniconda2-latest
(miniconda2-latest) cardamom@neptune ~/testDirectory $ pyenv local 3.4.3
cardamom@neptune ~/testDirectory $ python --version
Python 3.4.3
cardamom@neptune ~/testDirectory $
```

Does anyone know what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `miniconda3-latest` is a virtual environment, and `3.4.3` is just a different Python version.

`pyenv`, which is used to change current active Python version, isn't changing commandline prompt in any way, but `pyenv-virtualenv` plugin [does](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/blob/a3bc42cb93c5758ae967b4637829826800053689/bin/pyenv-sh-activate).

There is nothing wrong with it, it's just virtualenvs get special treatment in this situation.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why someone told me then to install `pyenv` instead of `pyenv-virtualenv` if the latter sounds more fully featured. Is that the case or are they for different purposes?

Comment: Of course. Generally you need both. `pyenv` is for switching Python versions, and `pyenv-virtualenv` is a plugin for isolating projects and their dependencies.